# Excel VBA: Moving a sheet to a new workbook while maintaining worksheet object association

Tags: vba, excel

The goal here is to set a worksheet object, then move that worksheet to a new workbook and continue to use that worksheet object. However, by moving that worksheet it appears that the worksheet object previously associated with it is lost.

To test:

Lets say we have two excel workbooks in the same folder named Book1.xlsb and Book2.xlsb each with one sheet in them named Sheet1. When we open Book1 we put in the below sub and try to move a sheet from the other using a worksheet object.

Everything "works", but the worksheet object is lost in the process, and throws an error as soon as you try to use it again. **Is it possible to move the worksheet to a new workbook and not lose that worksheet object association so that it can be referenced later?**

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("Book2.xlsb")

    Set ws = wb2.Sheets(1)

    ws.Name = "Sheet2" 'name changed to avoid conflict with the one already there
    ws.Move wb1.Sheets(1)

    MsgBox ws.Name 'this line throws an error, indicating that ws association has been lost

End Sub
```

Edit: 
If this is not possible, how can we reliably re-set that worksheet object to the one that we just moved?

Comment: No, you would have to recreate it if it's in a new Workbook. However, that's easy since you know the name of the sheet and you have the WorkBook object reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
ws.Move wb1.Sheets(1)
```

You alreay moved the sheet ws to the first sheet of the Book2.xlsb file

"Sheets(1)" means the first sheet of the file

So you can reset ws like this.

```
  Set ws = wb1.Sheets(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

To reset the ws object:

```
Set ws = wb1.WorkSheets("Sheet2")
```

If you dont know the name, you know it was moved to the last position, right?

```
Set ws = wb1.WorkSheets(wb1.WorkSheets.Count)
```

If it was moved to the first position, then:

```
Set ws = wb1.WorkSheets(1)
```

Comment: This only works if the sheet brought in is always named the same thing. In some cases, if we hadn't renamed that sheet to avoid the conflict for example, excel renames it automatically, to a new name which we don't know.

Comment: In your example code you are explicitly naming it. I'll give you another option.

Comment: In response to your edit, it doesn't appear as though it is added to the end. If yours showed different behavior then perhaps you are using a different version of excel, I am using Office Professional 2016

Comment: It has nothing to do with what version we are using. They dont change the object model. Where did it move it to? The first position? It's not just picking the position at random.

Comment: In my experiment, it was placed at the first position. But based on your answer, yours was placed at the end. This suggests to me that we cannot safely assume that it will always be placed at the first or last position.

Comment: No, I dont even have Excel open. It probably would have gone to the first position for me too if I had been actually doing it too. I simply made an assumption that it would be moved after existing worksheets.